# unable to run bin file after chmod

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Good day, I`ve been trying to install PMP on Ubuntu 20.04, after doing:

```
chmod a+x ManageEngine_PMP.bin
```

Im not sure if there is something missing or whats happening, because when I do

```
./ManageEngine_PMP.bin
```

got the following message:

```
./ManageEngine_PMP.bin: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./ManageEngine_PMP.bin: line 1: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">'
```

this happens in WSL2 and AWS EC2 Ubuntu

Please help

Comment: That file is not an executable object file, it's an HTML text file.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, the weird part is that the commands are from the installation instructions from PMP: 
Download the file ManageEngine_PMP.bin for linux.
Execute the command chmod a+x <file-name> to assign the executable permission.
Execute the command: ./<file_name>.

Comment: You must have downloaded something wrong.

Comment: You downloaded the html communications between the hosts, not the specific binary executable. (if you right-clicked and chose save file as ... sometimes that is just another link to the mirror holding the actual file). I suspect that is what happened. If you ever have a question about what a file is, just check with the `file` command, e.g. `file ManageEngine_PMP.bin`. If it isn't an ELF executable -- you have your answer.

Comment: all of you were right, just downloaded the correct one, best regards.